# How to use "Views Bulk Operations" module to delete Feed items in batch?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Drupal 7.x, how to use "Views Bulk Operations" module to delete Feed items in batch?
I've installed VBO module, but I don't know hot to use it, it have no configuraton menu, and I didn't find any clear instructions how to use it for my task. Also, VBO module requires Entity API module as a dependency. Can anybody post detailed instruction how to configure VBO for deleting feed items?

Comment: VBO is all about Views and Operations. You need to create a View that lists specific items that you want to perform operations to. There was a great screencast by Johan Falk at nodeone.se

Comment: Are there better alternatives for this simple operation, to batch delete all nodes of given type(feed item)?

Comment: In the feed source node page, you will see a tab to delete all items created from the current source.

Comment: I have about 1600 old feed items (from old feeds). In Admin > Content menu, I want to select all items, but there is no option to "Select All", I can only select separate items. Is there module or fix allowing to select all checkboxes?

Comment: I ended up using Devel module and it Devel Generate module to solve my task, and deleted all nodes (feed items) in batch.